# How to give discount to simple product under a bundle product?

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

I have bundle products which has 5 simple products as its options to be selected (Say, Product-A,Product-B,Product-C,Product-D,Product-E)

I want to design a coupon code which should offer like this:
If I purchase a bundle products and if that includes Product-C in its selection, then there should be 100% discount for the price included for Product-C and rest prices would be calculated as it is.

Whereas if the bundle product doesn't includes Product-C in its selection, then no deduction in price for that particular bundle product.

So, If I am selecting 3 bundle products, 2 of them having Product-C and if coupon code applied, then it should reduce price amount for Product-C for those 2 products but should be no effect in rest of the bundle product.

Is there a way to do this?